# DNS Mapping or maybe CNAME related

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I have a small saas where each customers gets own application instance. Each application instance has a DNS like *company*.example.com.

A customer (let's say X) asked me if instead of *customerX*.example.com he can have his application instance mapped to his domain: something like app.his-domain.com

My initial though was to ask him to include a CNAME DNS record like this:

> ```
> CNAME:
>
> app.his-domain.com -> customerX.example.com
> ```

and on my site add a new server_name for nginx :

> ```
> server {
>
> server_name customerX.example.com app.his-domain.com;
>
> proxy_pass: https://backend;
>
> }
> ```

But that won't work because of TLS certificates which are **only for .example.com subdomains**!

Question:

how is this DNS mapping thingy supposed to work? I have hard times even googling about it because I don't know the "official terms" for it. CNAME idea comes from my limited experience with DNS. So it might be a complete non-sense...

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? You would just get the TLS certificate and go on with your life.

Comment: ok, when that is the way to go, then great! I just wanted to validate my approach.

Comment: Before starting a TLS handshake (and hence certificates checks) a system has to do a TCP/IP connection. Before doing a TCP/IP connection the system has to find out the remote IP addresses. For that, it uses the DNS, most probably. At the end it gets an IP address, no matter if it was a direct `A` record or through 10 `CNAME`, the end is an IP address, or an error. With that IP address, the TLS handshake can then start. As you can see, once in TLS layer, the fact that there has been a `CNAME` is completely lost and hence irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, good insight!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing CNAMES with HTTP redirect. A CNAME just translates during DNS lookup to an IP, but when the client initiates the HTTPS session to the server, it'll still use the original DNS name in the HTTP headers, hence you get a certificate error because NGINX is serving the certificate for `.example.com`.

All you need to do to fix this is ask the client to issue a certificate for `app.his-domain.com` and have your NGINX serve this certificate for clients requesting the site `app.his-domain.com`.

Another way to fix this would be to host a redirect on your server, where NGINX tells the client 301 Permanently Moved to `client.example.com`, but this has the negative aspect that you're client then would see `client.example.com` in the browser address bar, which kind of negates the whole point of having a custom domain.